# Appcelerator photo upload location of files on Mac

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

## Appcelerator and Titanium Studio

I am testing photo upload to Arrow. Where is the location for photo.jpg on a Mac (El Capitan) using iPad configuration to run.
Code :
ACS.Photos.create({     photo: Titanium.Filesystem.getFile('photo.jpg'),

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to photos on your Mac. You can only use the pictures on the device.

If you want to put a image from your Mac to the simulator, you can drag and drop it.